Django: динамическое обновление списка в форме
Проблема с отображением списка в форме при выборе города: JavaScript и AJAX не обновляют содержимое. Как исправить?
Есть функция по оформлению заказа (create_order), которая обрабатывает форму. В форме есть поле (country) - город. Задумка такая, хочу чтобы пользователь выбирал свой город и видел отделения Новой Почты в своем городе.
Есть две функции которые обрабатывают город и выводят эти отделения, но в Django они не работают. Подскажите, как это сделать.
views.py:
def create_order(request):
    warehouses = []
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CreateOrderForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                with transaction.atomic():
                    if request.user.is_authenticated:
                        user = request.user
                        cart_items = Cart.objects.filter(user=user)
                    else:
                        session_key = request.session.session_key
                        cart_items = Cart.objects.filter(session_key=session_key)

                    if cart_items.exists():
                        # Создать заказ
                        if request.user.is_authenticated:
                            order = Order.objects.create(
                                user=user,
                                phone_number=form.cleaned_data["phone_number"],
                                country=form.cleaned_data["country"],
                                delivery_method=form.cleaned_data["delivery_method"],
                                delivery_address=form.cleaned_data["delivery_address"],
                                comment=form.cleaned_data["comment"],
                            )
                        else:
                            order = Order.objects.create(
                                session_key=request.session.session_key,
                                phone_number=form.cleaned_data["phone_number"],
                                country=form.cleaned_data["country"],
                                delivery_method=form.cleaned_data["delivery_method"],
                                delivery_address=form.cleaned_data["delivery_address"],
                                comment=form.cleaned_data["comment"],
                            )

                        # Создать заказанные товары
                        for cart_item in cart_items:
                            product = cart_item.product
                            title = cart_item.product.title
                            price = cart_item.product.price
                            amount = cart_item.amount
                            OrderItem.objects.create(
                                order=order,
                                product=product,
                                title=title,
                                price=price,
                                amount=amount,
                            )

                        # Очищение корзины пользователя
                        cart_items.delete()

                        # Получение и отправка отделений в форме JsonResponse
                        country = form.cleaned_data["country"]
                        country_ref = get_city_ref(country)
                        warehouses = get_warehouses(country_ref)

            except ValidationError as e:
                messages.warning(request, str(e))
                return redirect("product:index")

    else:
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            initial = {
                "email": request.user.email,
                "first_name": request.user.first_name,
                "last_name": request.user.last_name,
                "middle_name": request.user.middle_name,
            }
            form = CreateOrderForm(initial=initial)
        else:
            form = CreateOrderForm()

    context = {"form": form, "warehouses": warehouses}
    return render(request, "orders/create_order.html", context)

forms.py:
class CreateOrderForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    first_name = forms.CharField()
    middle_name = forms.CharField()
    last_name = forms.CharField()
    phone_number = forms.CharField()
    country = forms.CharField()
    delivery_method = forms.CharField()
    delivery_address = forms.CharField()
    payment_on_get = forms.CharField()
    comment = forms.CharField(required=False)

utils.py:
def get_city_ref(country):
    """Получает Ref определенного города."""

    country_ref = ""
    json = {
        "apiKey": "",
        "modelName": "Address",
        "calledMethod": "getCities",
        "methodProperties": {
            "FindByString": country,  # Передаем значение из формы
        },
    }

    response = requests.post(
        "https://api.novaposhta.ua/v2.0/json/", json=json, timeout=1
    )

    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()["data"]
        for country_item in data:
            if country_item["Description"] == country:
                country_ref = country_item["Ref"]

        return country_ref

    else:
        print("Ошибка при получении country_ref:", response.text)


def get_warehouses(country_ref):
    """Получаем отделения из опеределенного города используя Ref."""

    warehouses = []

    # Получение отделений
    json_data = {
        "apiKey": "b0b6ea3934d1d018b3155eb1658c2e36",
        "modelName": "AddressGeneral",
        "calledMethod": "getWarehouses",
        "methodProperties": {
            "CityRef": country_ref,  # Город
        },
    }

    response = requests.post(
        "https://api.novaposhta.ua/v2.0/json/", json=json_data, timeout=1
    )

    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()["data"]

        for item in data:
            if item["Description"].split()[0] != "Поштомат":
                warehouses.append(item["Description"])

        return JsonResponse({"warehouses": warehouses})

create_order.html
<form action="{% url 'orders:create_order' %}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="row g-3">
              <div class="col-12">
                <label for="id_email" class="form-label">E-mail <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="id_email" value="{% if form.email.value %}{{ form.email.value }}{% endif %}" placeholder="you@example.com" />
                {% if form.email.errors %}
                  <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show">{{ form.email.errors }}</div>
                {% endif %}
                <hr />
              </div>

              <h4 class="text-uppercase fw-semibold mb-1">АДРЕСА ДЛЯ ВИСТАВЛЕННЯ РАХУНКУ</h4>

              <div class="col-sm-4">
                <label for="id_first_name" class="form-label">Ім'я <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" id="id_first_name" value="{% if form.first_name.value %}{{ form.first_name.value }}{% endif %}" />
                {% if form.first_name.errors %}
                  <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show">{{ form.first_name.errors }}</div>
                {% endif %}
              </div>

              <div class="col-sm-4">
                <label for="id_last_name" class="form-label">Прізвище <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" id="id_last_name" value="{% if form.last_name.value %}{{ form.last_name.value }}{% endif %}" />
                {% if form.last_name.errors %}
                  <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show">{{ form.last_name.errors }}</div>
                {% endif %}
              </div>

              <div class="col-sm-4">
                <label for="id_middle_name" class="form-label">По батькові <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="middle_name" id="id_middle_name" value="{% if form.middle_name.value %}{{ form.middle_name.value }}{% endif %}" />
                {% if form.middle_name.errors %}
                  <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show">{{ form.middle_name.errors }}</div>
                {% endif %}
              </div>

              <div class="col-12">
                <label for="id_phone_number" class="form-label">Номер телефона <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone_number" id="id_phone_number" value="{% if form.phone_number.value %}{{ form.phone_number.value }}{% endif %}" placeholder="У форматі XXX XXX XXX XXX" />
                {% if form.phone_number.errors %}
                  <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show">{{ form.phone_number.errors }}</div>
                {% endif %}
              </div>

              <div class="col-12">
                <label for="id_country" class="form-label">Ваш населений пункт <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>

                <select class="form-select" name="country" id="id_country">
                  <option>Вибіріть ваш населений пункт</option>
                  <option value="Вінниця" {% if form.country.value == "Вінниця" %}selected{% endif %}>Вінниця</option>
                  <option value="Дніпро" {% if form.country.value == "Дніпро" %}selected{% endif %}>Дніпро</option>
                  <option value="Житомир" {% if form.country.value == "Житомир" %}selected{% endif %}>Житомир</option>
                  <option value="Запоріжжя" {% if form.country.value == "Запоріжжя" %}selected{% endif %}>Запоріжжя</option>
                  <option value="Івано-Франківськ" {% if form.country.value == "Івано-Франківськ" %}selected{% endif %}>Івано-Франківськ</option>
                  <option value="Київ" {% if form.country.value == "Київ" %}selected{% endif %}>Київ</option>
                  <option value="Кропивницький" {% if form.country.value == "Кропивницький" %}selected{% endif %}>Кропивницький</option>
                  <option value="Луцьк" {% if form.country.value == "Луцьк" %}selected{% endif %}>Луцьк</option>
                  <option value="Львів" {% if form.country.value == "Львів" %}selected{% endif %}>Львів</option>
                  <option value="Миколаїв" {% if form.country.value == "Миколаїв" %}selected{% endif %}>Миколаїв</option>
                  <option value="Одеса" {% if form.country.value == "Одеса" %}selected{% endif %}>Одеса</option>
                  <option value="Полтава" {% if form.country.value == "Полтава" %}selected{% endif %}>Полтава</option>
                  <option value="Рівне" {% if form.country.value == "Рівне" %}selected{% endif %}>Рівне</option>
                  <option value="Суми" {% if form.country.value == "Суми" %}selected{% endif %}>Суми</option>
                  <option value="Тернопіль" {% if form.country.value == "Тернопіль" %}selected{% endif %}>Тернопіль</option>
                  <option value="Харків" {% if form.country.value == "Харків" %}selected{% endif %}>Харків</option>
                  <option value="Херсон" {% if form.country.value == "Херсон" %}selected{% endif %}>Херсон</option>
                  <option value="Хмельницький" {% if form.country.value == "Хмельницький" %}selected{% endif %}>Хмельницький</option>
                  <option value="Черкаси" {% if form.country.value == "Черкаси" %}selected{% endif %}>Черкаси</option>
                  <option value="Чернівці" {% if form.country.value == "Чернівці" %}selected{% endif %}>Чернівці</option>
                  <option value="Чернігів" {% if form.country.value == "Чернігів" %}selected{% endif %}>Чернігів</option>
                </select>

                {% if form.country.errors %}
                  <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show">{{ form.country.errors }}</div>
                {% endif %}
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-12 d-flex flex-column">
                <label for="id_delivery_method" class="form-label">Спосіб доставки <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline mb-3">
                  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="delivery_method" id="id_delivery_method" value="0" 
                    {% if form.delivery_method.value == '0' %}checked{% endif %}/>
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="id_delivery_method">Meest пошта відділення</label>
                  {% if form.delivery_method.errors %}
                    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show">{{ form.delivery_method.errors }}</div>
                  {% endif %}
                </div>
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline mb-3">
                  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="delivery_method" id="id_delivery_method" value="1" 
                    {% if form.delivery_method.value == '1' %}checked{% endif %}/>
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="id_delivery_method">Нова почта відділення</label>
                  {% if form.delivery_method.errors %}
                    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show">{{ form.delivery_method.errors }}</div>
                  {% endif %}
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-12">
                <label for="id_delivery_address" class="form-label">Знайти відділення <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>

                <select class="form-select" name="delivery_address" id="id_delivery_address">
                  <option>Знайти відділення</option>
                  {% for warehouse in warehouses %}
                    <option value="{{ warehouse }}">{{ warehouse }}</option>
                  {% endfor %}
                </select>

                {% if form.delivery_addres.errors %}
                  <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show">{{ form.delivery_addres.errors }}</div>
                {% endif %}
              </div>

              <div class="col-12">
                <label for="id_payment_on_get" class="form-label">Спосіб оплати <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                <div class="">
                  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="payment_on_get" id="id_payment_on_get" value="1" checked />
                  <label for="id_payment_on_get" class="form-label">При отриманні</label>

                  {% if form.payment_on_get.errors %}
                    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show">{{ form.payment_on_get.errors }}</div>
                  {% endif %}
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-12">
                <label for="id_comment" class="form-label">Коментар (необов'язково)</label>
                <textarea type="text" class="form-control h-auto" name="comment" id="id_comment" value="{% if form.comment.value %}{{ form.comment.value }}{% endif %}" rows="3"></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>

            <hr class="my-4" />

            <button class="w-100 btn btn-main btn-lg mb-5" type="submit">Купити зараз</button>
          </form>

Буду очень признателен. Спасибо!
